# Задание cron для проверки наличия процесса

Tags: ubuntu, cron, процесс, проверка, планировщик-задач

Мне нужен пример скрипта для планировщика Ubuntu, чтобы он проверял наличие процесса и если процесс не запущен, то запускал его (с параметрами).
Так же, в любом случае раз сутки убивал процесс и запускал его заново.

Comment: Я бы использовал "штатные" средства чтобы не изобретать велосипед. Например monit

Comment: Ты щас описал юниты в `systemd`.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы разделил на два скрипта. Один вставил бы в крон с выполнением "каждую минуту" - проверка запущен ли процесс, а второй - принудительный перезапуск раз в день.

Для запуска если "нет его":

```
#!/bin/bash
ret=$(ps -ax | grep httpd | wc -l)
if [ "$ret" -eq 1 ]
    then {
        service https start
        exit 1
    }
fi;
```

Для перезапуска раз в сутки:

```
#!/bin/bash
service httpd restart
```